# read.table parses a text file in an unexpected way

Tags: r, memory

I'm attempting to read a big matrix using R (64 bit). The matrix has 14.000 columns and 900 rows. The problem is that at a certain point of the matrix, R splits a row in a new line. The split occurs more than one time. I suppose the problem is in the R memory even if I'm using a 64 bit. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Just 1 row example: (from shell Unix)

```
SELT 0.00134 TGH 0.776554 P53 0.23436 MYC 0.2351 BRCA 0.7654.... # (the line has 9.573 columns)
```

after R `read.delim()` or `read.table()` (just reading the file):

```
SELT 0.00134 TGH 0.776554 P53 0.23436   
MYC 0.2351 BRCA 0.7654....
```

`MYC 0.2351 BRCA 0.7654` are wrongly on a new line.

Eleonora

Comment: What do you mean by “split in a new line”? Lines are a concept of textual input/output formats. Are you talking about the representation of the matrix in the console window or when written to some file? Where does the matrix come from, and where do you see the split?

Comment: What is the result if you apply the `dim` function on your data?

Comment: It would help to see the functions you use to read the matrix. Are you using `read.csv`? Getting the data from an SQL server? If you know which line(s) are being split, try taking a look at them in another program (e.g., vim if it's a text-containing file).

Comment: Ok, the situation is this: a .txt file is the input for R. I used read.delim or read.table to read the data frame but the row containing for ex: a, b, c, d, e (here only 5 elements are shown but the row can contain 5.000 columns) is splitted so that a, b, c are on the same line, instead d and e are on a new line just during the reading the input file.

Comment: I tried to read the same file just using shell commands and no split occurs.

Comment: the file has the following dimensions: as from shell Unix the file has correctly 900 rows, instead after R reading the file has 1022 rows due to split. The file is an output of an in parallel analysis. the outputs of the parallelization have been concatenated so the file contains rows of different length (different numbers of columns if you read the matrix using Excel foe example).

Comment: How is your file delimited? Did you make a typo when your write "14.000" or is the "." significant in terms of the locale in which you or your OS resides? That is not a big set of data so there must be some unescaped character that R is catching and that might be due to the functions you are using to read in the data assuming things about how your data are delimited. Please post the first few lines of the text file so we can help.

Comment: 14.000 is the maximum number a row can have depending on the output of the analysis. Generally, rows have less than 14.000 columns due to some thresholds we applied to the output but it can happen.

Comment: Gavin, I edited my question. Do you need more informations?

Comment: Please create a self contained example which reproduces your problem, so a small text file (e.g. put it on dropbox), plus the R code that reads it. Right now a lot of things could go wrong, but we have no way of checking.

Comment: To extend Paul H's comment:  make sure the small sample data includes exactly the lines which fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. My solution is to put a head in .txt file with the names: "V1", "V2"..."Vmax_number_of_columns". With this it worked.

Answer (score 1):

we verified that the output of the parallel analysis we performed was corrupted, so this is the reason why R "failed" to read correctly the file. anyway thanks a lot for your help!